# with *.aligned.sorted.bam.featureCounts but without *.ex.featureCounts or *.in.featureCounts

Tags: command, ln

Anyone,

I played with

`$zUMIs-zUMIs.0.0.6/zUMIs-master.sh -f barcoderead_HEK.1mio.fq.gz -r cDNAread_HEK.1mio.fq.gz -n 1 -g /home/li/reference/hg38_chr22 -a /home/li/reference/hg38_chr22/GRCh38.84.chr22.gtf  -c 1-6 -m 7-16 -l 50  -o /home/li/li01`

In my output directory:

I only have `*.aligned.sorted.bam.featureCounts` file but without `*.ex.featureCounts` and `*.in.featureCounts`.

If I put these two files in my directory, it runs well.

I tried to following https://github.com/sdparekh/zUMIs/issues/38.

"It seems that in your system, the "ln" command is missing. We use it to link the .ex and .in files!"

I am working on Linux (Ubuntu) system.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ln
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ln
```

Really appreciate any suggestion and help!

Best,

yue

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's better to ask bioinformatics linked questions on biostars https://www.biostars.org/ :)

And normally ln has to be installed in R